# Failed updating and uninstalling app with ADB

Tags: applications, adb, nexus-4

I installed Better Battery Stats (BBS) v2 from XDA and quickly realized that the actual required version is 2.1. So I tried to uninstall BBS via ADB but that failed because BBS is a system app.

Now when I try to install the new version, I got:

```
bash-3.2$ adb install BetterBatteryStats_xdaedition_2.1.0.0_B4.apk
3925 KB/s (3671858 bytes in 0.913s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/BetterBatteryStats_xdaedition_2.1.0.0_B4.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

And when I try to uninstall it, I got:

```
bash-3.2$ adb uninstall com.asksven.betterbatterystats_xdaedition
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

Can anyone point out how can I resolve this issue? I just want BBS 2.1 Beta. I am using a Nexus 4 running stock 5.1.1 (rooted).

Comment: Did you try using a system uninstaller app to see what happens? // Somebody somewhere suggested to use `pm uninstall <pkg>` and see what happens. Someone else said that having multiple accounts results in this. Don't know the reasoning but it kinda helped them. // May be you can try deleting the apk from /system manually and the associated data of it.

Comment: Can you run adb as sudo? sudo adb install BetterBatteryStats_xdaedition_2.1.0.0_B4.apk  You may need to give full path when you do so though.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following:

```
adb shell //open adb shell
su //get root permissions
pm uninstall your.package.name //uninstall the app
```

Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try `Adb shell uninstall -k --user 0 packagename`

Comment: please don't post untested solutions